# Setup allure reports with jUnit5 and Gradle

Tags: gradle, junit5, allure

I am trying to setup gradle+allure+jUnit5

```
Allure CLI version: 2.13.9
Gradle version: 6.8.3
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.8.1'
}

group 'org.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    testImplementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-junit5:2.13.9'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I am running test via gradle:

```
gradle clean test
```

I see results generated under "build/allure-results"

When I am running "gradle allureReport" or "gradle allureServe" I am getting following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'allureReport' not found in root project 'gradle_junit_allure'.
...
```

Moreover, when I am trying to generate report with Allure CLI tool, I see report generated but no data in it:

```
allure generate -c build/ -o build/allure-report
Report successfully generated to build\allure-report
```

Result:

[image]

Please note that I have .json files generated inside build/allure-results

And one more issue:

I have allure.properties file under test/resources with following property:

```
allure.results.directory=target/allure-results
```

Looks like this option is not applied during results generation as they are generated under: build/allure-results

Could someone please point me on what I am doing wrong and how I can properly setup mentioned stack of tools?